# PayPal Webhook sends no POST data

Tags: php, paypal

Configured my PayPal webhook successfully to be notified of all events.

PayPal calls my webhook (a simple script) when events occur... but does not send any POST data with it....

All PHP arrays are empty (**$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST**) except for **$_SERVER** of course.

What is going on?  The webhook simulator says that the events are sent/queued succesfully...

The **$_SERVER** array contains the suggested **HTTP_PAYPAL_...** headers and everything.... but the **$_POST** array is empty.

My webhook is written as follows...

```
<?php

require ('./ace-includes/ace_log.php');

ace_log(print_r($_POST, true));
ace_log(print_r($_REQUEST, true));
ace_log(print_r($_GET, true));
ace_log(print_r($_SERVER, true));

ace_sendlog("NOTIFY SCRIPT CALLED");

?>
```

Comment: What is `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']`?

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out....

You cannot use $_POST to get the data....

The data is contained in the HTTP file sent to the script.

In this case you MUST use

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

to get the data.

So for PayPal PHP webhooks you would do this....

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

This works and now I am getting all the data.

This really should be documented somewhere.... anywhere... but its not... and not obvious to an beginning PHP programmer.

Comment: Well, if you read the PHP documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php about $_POST : " An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request. "  But a PayPal Webhook does not use that content type; it sends JSON formatted data.  There are plenty of places that talk about how to read JSON over HTTP with PHP; it seems you found one of them to figure this out.

Comment: You definitely save my day!!!!!